# Mailchimp Template CSS

Tags: css, html-email, mailchimp, css-tables, email-templates

I used tables with inline css for the layout of my mailchimp template. There's a space between my to tables and I am trying to remove that space. I tried moving the height of the other td above my template and yet I can't remove the space. I tried margin top with negative value and it worked on the inspector and WYSIWYG of mailchimp but when I tried it on gmail, the margin top doesn't work when negative valued. Would Javascript be effective on this? would there be a way to make mailchimp render the negative value?

Comment: It would be great if you would share your code with us.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a white space between your table tags. Try to delete them, or use these hacks:

With comments:

```
<table>
...
</table><!-- 
--><table>
...
</table>
```

Without comments:

```
<table>
...
</table><table>
...
</table>
```